# Is there a key stroke to switch to a fullscreen app in Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces, expose

I normally switch around my virtual desktops using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>num</kbd>. Now, Exposé shows all the desktops and the fullscreen app whereupon clicking the fullscreen app rectangle will take me back to it. I'd rather do so via keyboard nav. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't work for me because I'm doing this with VMware where I have multiple windows open, one is fullscreen, others are not. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> seems to land me on whatever VMware window it randomly chooses.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure these shortcuts in `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Mission Control`

I think the default is control-option-left/right arrow, at least that's what I have it set to.

In mission control, you can also re-order the position of the desktops/full screen apps by dragging them around. I think by default they're ordered by most-recently used desktop, but you can change that (I can't remember how, that would be a separate question anyway).

Answer (score -1):

By default it's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

However, it doesn't work in all apps. Some don't do full screen and some pre-Lion apps retain their original full-screen keyboard shortcuts (e.g., Command-Shift-F in Firefox).

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to switch to an app running in fullscreen mode, not to enable/disable it.